# Treat Directories as Files in IIS

Tags: iis, mac-osx, hosting

some files on Mac OS X (such as .bundle or .mpkg) are considered directories in Windows, but can be used as files on Mac OS X (if you double-click them on Mac OSX, they execute for example), so the problem I have is that I want Mac users to download a .mpkg file from my server, but the problem is IIS considers it a directory and therefore you can't download it.

How can I let IIS treat this .mpkg as a file instead of a directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to remember here is that *the internet isn't a filesystem*. Any "special" behaviours that Mac OS X applies to a directory with [a specific extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bundle#Loadable_Bundles) won't be applied by your web browser.

The immediate solution that springs to mind is to wrap the directory into an archive of some description, such as Zip or your archive format of choice.